Relation between $-2/d$-norm and polynomial discriminant
Consider a homogeneous bivariate polynomial $f(x, y) = a_d x^d + a_{d-1} x^{d-1} y + \cdots + a_0 y^d$ of degree $d > 2$, and consider the “$-2/d$-norm”
$$\int_0^{2\pi} |f(\cos{\theta}, \sin{\theta})|^{-2/d} \, \mathrm{d} \theta.$$
Note that there are singularities in the integral, but they converge.
Numerically, the value of this integral seems to depend only on the discriminant of $f$. I am having trouble figuring out why this is the case.
This holds for the case $d = 2$ as well if $f$ is positive definite.

What is the conjectured connection between this integral and the discriminant? Also, if you can prove it for all positive definite $f$, then it probably holds for any $f$, because you have an algebraic identity in the coefficients $a_i$ holding on a sufficiently big set.
